# Consolidate repeating pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a script that develops certain strings of alphanumeric characters, separated by a dash `-`. I need to test the string to see if there are any sets of characters (the characters that lie in between the dashes) that are the same. If they are, I need to consolidate them. The repeating chars would always occur at the front in my case.

```
Examples:

KRS-KRS-454-L
would become:
KRS-454-L

DERP-DERP-545-P
would become:
DERP-545-P
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?php
$s = 'KRS-KRS-454-L';
echo preg_replace('/^(\w+)-(?=\1)/', '', $s);
?>
// KRS-454-L
```

This uses a *positive lookahead* `(?=...)` to check for repeated strings.

Note that `\w` also contains the underscore. If you want to limit to alphanumeric characters only, use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Also, I've anchored with `^` as you've mentioned: *"The repeating chars would always occur at the front [...]"*

Comment: mhyfritz What does (?=\1) mean? I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: @FinalForm: the `(?=)` is a *lookahead* and will match whatever is in the parentheses without actually consuming any text (hope that makes sense). The `\1` is a *backreference* and matches something you have captured before (in this case, the 1st group - `(\w+)`). If you would have a 2nd capturing group you would reference it with `\2`. Makes sense?

Comment: mhyfritz thank you, yes. this makes sense. How come I can't @ at your username?

Comment: @mhyfritz, @FinalForm: See this meta discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/97098/152620

Answer (score 3):

Try the pattern:

```
/([a-z]+)(?:-\1)*(.*)/i
```

and replace it with:

```
$1$2
```

A demo:

```
$tests = array(
  'KRS-KRS-454-L',
  'DERP-DERP-DERP-545-P',
  'OKAY-666-A'
);

foreach ($tests as $t) {
  echo preg_replace('/([a-z]+)(?:-\1)*(.*)/i', '$1$2', $t) . "\n";
}
```

produces:

```
KRS-454-L
DERP-545-P
OKAY-666-A
```

A quick explanation:

```
([a-z]+)  # group the first "word" in match group 1
(?:-\1)*  # match a hyphen followed by what was matched in 
          # group 1, and repeat it zero or more times
(.*)      # match the rest of the input and store it in group 2
```

the replacement string `$1$2` are replaced by what was matched by group 1 and group 2 in the pattern above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `((?:[A-Z-])+)\1{1}` and replaced the matched string by $1.

`\1` is used in connection with `{1}` in the above regex. It will look for repeating instance of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need [back references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Using perl syntax, this would work for you:

```
$line =~ s/([A-Za-z0-9]+-)\1+/\1/gi;
```